# Unable to load DebuggerVisualizer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reflection, debuggervisualizer

I am having a similar problem, I created a debug visualiser:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;

[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(MatrixVisualizers.MatrixVisualiser), typeof(VisualizerObjectSource), Description="Visualize a matrix" )]

namespace MatrixVisualizers
{
    public class MatrixVisualiser : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
    protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(objectProvider.GetObject().ToString());
    }
}
```

}

Which I use explicitly on a base class in a different assembly:

```
[Serializable]
[DebuggerVisualizer(typeof(MatrixVisualiser))]
public abstract class TwoDMatrix<T> : IMatrix<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>
{
...
}
```

However when I copy the dll to c:\program files (x86)\Visual Studio 11.0\common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers I do get the option to use the visualiser when I hit a breakpoint in the code, but selecting the visualiser throws a FileNotFoundException.  It correctly identifies the assembly (including version number 1.1.0.0).

Incidentally, I am currently running this as a unit test which I am trying to debug.

I have tried using FusionLogger to diagnose this, but it is not showing as an error in the log.

This may be realted to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118023/how-to-setup-debugger-visualizer-for-vs2012

Comment: Your test project also has a dependency on the visualizer DLL through the attribute.  It will never find that DLL in the VS directory.  Not sure how that's supposed to work, examples show visualizers for framework classes and use the [DebuggerVisualizer] Target property.  You'd be better off just keeping the visualizer DLL in the test project build directory.

Comment: Adding the visualizer dll to the test build directory similarly does not work unless I explicitly load the assembly in the specific test that I want to debug and visualize in.
I.e. I have to add
`Assembly.Load("MatrixVisualizers, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"`
at the start of the test.  This seems totally wrong to me, and the dll should surely be loaded by the IDE, not my code

Comment: To clarify that, I have written a very simple console app with the main function
`Assembly.Load("MatrixVisualizers, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

var sut = GetAMatrix();

Console.WriteLine(sut);`

If I break on the `Console.WriteLine` and visualize it is successful (wit the dll in my build directory), but if I remove the first line it fails